# Достать сущности из базы mySQL с сортировкой

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Использую связку jpa/hibernate, нужно достать из таблицы сущности и представить их в отсортированном виде. Как предпочтительнее и быстрее это сделать? Выполнить запрос с сортировкой(например: `createQuery("select m from MyEntity m where m.date > :param order by m.date desc ", MyEntity.class);`) или достать сущности из базы как есть, а отсортировать уже в исходном коде?

Comment: Учитывая, что у вас условие выборки по тому же полю, что и order by то при наличии индекса на этом поле БД сделает сортировку гораздо быстрее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. в условие запроса и сортировке используется одно поле лучше это сделать в запросе.